# Join Criteria Priority Issue

Tags: sql

Hello Stack overflow community,

I am new to SQL, so I might be overlooking something simple. 
For some reason when I add the t2 criteria to the WHERE clause, the t1. criteria are no longer followed. 
For example when I run the query without the specifications on Diagnosis, the I only see inpatients between the specified AdmitDateTimes, that are 18 years and older. However when I add the Diagnosis criteria, my joined table has patients of any status, from any AdmitDateTime and with any age.

Any and all assistance is greatly appreciated

THANKS!

```
SELECT TOP 1000 
       ReportTraining.dbo.IatricGetAge(t1.BirthDateTime,t1.ServiceDateTime) AS 'Age'
      ,t1.[SourceID]
      ,t1.[VisitID]
      ,t1.[AbstractStatusDateTime]
      ,t1.[AccountNumber]
      ,t1.[AdmitDateTime]
      ,t1.[AdmitFromEr]
      ,t1.[BirthDateTime]
      ,t1.[DischargeDateTime]
      ,t1.[DischargeDispositionID]
      ,t1.[DischargeDispositionName]
      ,t1.[FacilityID]
      ,t1.[FacilityName]
      ,t1.[LocationID]
      ,t1.[LocationName]
      ,t1.[Name]
      ,t1.[ObservationDateTime]
      ,t1.[ObservationPatient]
      ,t1.[PatientStatusName]
      ,t1.[PtStatus]
      ,t1.[ReasonForVisit]
      ,t1.[ServiceDateTime]
      ,t1.[Status]
      ,t1.[UnitNumber]
      ,t1.[RowUpdateDateTime]
      ,t1.[AbstractID]
      ,t1.[PatientID]
      ,t2.[VisitID]
      ,t2.[DiagnosisSeqID]
      ,t2.[Diagnosis]
      ,t2.[AbstractID]
  FROM  [Livedb].[dbo].[AbstractData] t1
        INNER JOIN [Livedb].[dbo].[AbsDrgDiagnoses] t2      ON (t2.AbstractID = t1.AbstractID   AND
                                                                t2.VisitID    = t1.VisitID)

  WHERE t1.AdmitDateTime BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-01-31' AND
  t1.PatientStatusName LIKE 'INPATIENT' AND
  ReportTraining.dbo.IatricGetAge(t1.BirthDateTime,t1.ServiceDateTime)>= '18' AND
  t2.Diagnosis IN ('G62.1' , 'I42.6' , 'K29.2' , 'K70' , 'T39' , 'T40' , 'T41.3' , 'T51.91XA' , 'Z71.41' , 'Z72.51') OR
  t2.Diagnosis LIKE 'F%'       AND
  t2.Diagnosis NOT LIKE 'F01%' AND
  t2.Diagnosis NOT LIKE 'F02%' AND
  t2.Diagnosis NOT LIKE 'F03%' AND
  t2.Diagnosis NOT LIKE 'F17%' AND
  t2.Diagnosis NOT LIKE 'F70%' AND
  t2.Diagnosis NOT LIKE 'F71%' AND
  t2.Diagnosis NOT LIKE 'F72%' AND 
  t2.Diagnosis NOT LIKE 'F73%' AND
  t2.Diagnosis NOT LIKE 'F74%' AND
  t2.Diagnosis NOT LIKE 'F75%' AND 
  t2.Diagnosis NOT LIKE 'F76%' AND
  t2.Diagnosis NOT LIKE 'F77%' AND
  t2.Diagnosis NOT LIKE 'F78%' AND
  t2.Diagnosis NOT LIKE 'F79%';
```

Comment: Can you clarify what your exact question is?

Answer (score 3):

`AND` is evaluated before `OR` - whenever you mix them you should add parentheses to make sure your conditions are grouped appropriately.  In your case you likely need to group the two `OR` conditions so they are evaluated as one group:

```
WHERE ... AND ... AND ...
   AND
   (  t2.Diagnosis IN (...) OR
      t2.Diagnosis LIKE 'F%'    
   )
   AND
       ....
```

Comment: Hi D Stanley,
Thanks so much for the feedback. Yes it was a parentheses issue. Separating out the OR clause did the trick. 
I really appreciate everyone's input and the assistance to a new SQLer!

Best,
Mike